# Are there any major organizations or individuals in China who have expressed pro-Ukranian views in their current conflict?

Tags: russian-federation, china, armed-conflict, ukraine

In the current Russia-Ukraine war, China has professed neutrality but articles like [this](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/diplomacy/article/3174934/ukraine-war-most-chinese-believe-backing-russia-their-national) and [this](https://www.voanews.com/a/ukraine-invasion-sparks-controversial-commentary-on-chinese-social-media-/6467187.html) suggest that support for Russia is high amongst its citizens along with soft support from the Chinese government as shown [here](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/09/11/world/russia-says-that-a-senior-chinese-official-expressed-support-for-the-invasion-of-ukraine.html).

Are there any major individuals or organizations in China which have expressed an explicity pro-Ukranian stance in the conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Chinese government's official position is neutrality. From a strategic standpoint there is no way they would assist Western Sanction of Russia. They would trade with Russia as usual with anything that is not weapon (but not including those that could be weaponized). In a way, China not selling weapon to Russia is already a big help to Ukriane.

Due to anti-US sentiment, there is a lot of Chinese netizen in Weibo and Bilibili supporting Russia and the sentiment that the Euromaiden in 2014 is a CIA-backed coup. However, if you go to ZhiHu and other Chinese Social Media or website, you can see lots of pro-Ukraine, anti-Russia voices too. These posts exists and have existed for a while, and the state censor did nothing.

But you won't see any major public figure publicly support Russia's war (just promoting Russian culture and scenery in Russia doesn't count) or denouce it and support Ukriane. All public figure must obey the Party Line, which is neutrality.

Answer (score 0):

Xi Jinping have congratulated Volodymyr Zelenskyy:

> On July 13, 2021 President of Ukraine Volodymyr Zelenskyy had a phone
> conversation with President of the People's Republic of China Xi
> Jinping. The leaders **exchanged congratulations** on the occasion of the
> 10th anniversary of the establishment of a strategic partnership
> between Ukraine and China and reaffirmed their mutual commitment to
> its development and deepening.

During the war, the Foreign Minister of Ukraine Dmytro Kuleba and Chinese Foreign Minister Wang Yi held telephone conversations in March and April 2022 during which they agreed that ending the war against Ukraine is in the interests of peace, food security and international trade ([source](https://china.mfa.gov.ua/en/partnership/political-relations-between-ukraine-and-china)).

Chinese proposal on the settlement of Ukrainian crisis can be found [here](https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/zxxx_662805/202302/t20230224_11030713.html). It calls for respect of **territorial integrity of all countries**.

China is keeping the neutral stance. USA is incomparably more important consumer of they production than Russia is ([source](https://wits.worldbank.org/CountryProfile/en/Country/CHN/Year/LTST/TradeFlow/Export/Partner/by-country/Product/Total)), hence there are things to lose for them by annoying USA too much.

Comment: Does 2021 count as "in the current conflict"?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution The conflict has started on February 20, 2014.